# Bluetooth beacon launch app or generate push notification

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

Is it possible to achieve something like geofenced launching of an application, but using bluetooth beacons instead of GPS? I.e. when the phone gets a close to a device with a particular id it will launch the app (or somehow generate a push notification which could in turn launch the app)?

Comment: Did you find any way to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not in iOS 6 or 5. You would be interested to look at the docs for the upcoming release however. You might find something in there to be pleasantly surprising.

Comment: Is it possible to do in iOS 7 now? I've been looking but didn't find anything useful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes it's more or less the same as geofencing - all the iBeacon stuff is in CoreLocation (not CoreBluetooth like i was expecting)

Comment: Thanks @jonydep. I was able to generate a push notification in proximity of the beacon, even when the app was in background. Although it didn't generate a notification when device screen was off. It also didn't generate it when app was closed(..not in background but closed). 

Instead of getting a notification and asking user to click on it to go to the app, is there a way to directly open the app programatically?

Comment: no i don't think this is possible. it wouldn't be good to let an app do that - the user should always be able to kill it and not then have any possibility of it starting up of its own accord

Comment: @jonydep my use case, that is not harming the user in any way, would be for an app to launch (or at least present a lock screen notification) as soon as you start your car. I'd like to do this with a USB powered beacon in the car. This is commonly done in driving aid apps on Android and Windows Phone — using either NFC or bluetooth.